# MySQL left join filter

Tags: mysql

I have two related tables as shown below that I need to JOIN to get all the new and updated records.  These are representative examples with a simplified table structure.

The first table is a table of items e.g. 'Notes' that contains all existing notes as well as 'new' notes and updates to existing notes.

The second table contains the details of the pending changes/updates to a note.
For example, if a note has been modified, then that row is cloned with the modifications and a
row is added to pendingUpdates table with the id of the original note, the id of the row with the updates and the user who made the update.  If a new note is added the workflow is similar expect the original id and modified id refer to the same row.

```
Notes:
+----+---------------------+----------------------------+
| id | title               | text                       | 
+----+---------------------+----------------------------+
|  1 | this is a test note | blah blah blah             | 
|  2 | note 2              | sdfsadfasdf                | 
|  3 | note 3              | jklhjklhjklhjk             |
|  4 | note 3              | This is an update to note3 |
|  5 | note 3              | another update             | 
|  6 | note 4              | new note                   | 
+----+---------------------+----------------------------+

pendingUpdates:
+----+------------+---------+------+
| id | originalId | cloneId | user |
+----+------------+---------+------+
|  1 |          3 |       4 |    1 |
|  2 |          3 |       5 |    1 |
|  3 |          6 |       6 |    2 |
+----+------------+---------+------+
```

What I would like to do is to run a SELECT to get all Notes and include if that note has changes (with the list of updates) and any New notes.

So for the above example that would return row 1,2,3, and 6.  Row 3 would also have 4,5 listed as updates.

Example of desired results:

```
+----+------------+-------------+------+--------+---------------------+
| id | hasChanges | isNewRecord | p_id | clones | title               |
+----+------------+-------------+------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | no         | no          | NULL |  NULL  | this is a test note |
|  2 | no         | no          | NULL |  NULL  | note 2              |
|  3 | yes        | no          |    1 |  4,5   | note 3              |
|  6 | yes        | yes         |    3 |  6     | note 4              |
+----+------------+-------------+------+--------+---------------------+
```

I've tried many different combinations of queries and have yet to get exactly what I need.
Here's what I've got that is pretty close, but is including rows 4 & 5 in the result set which I don't want.

```
SELECT 
    o.id,
    if(o.id = p.originalId, 'yes', 'no') AS hasChanges,
    if(p.cloneId = p.originalId,
        'yes',
        'no') AS isNewRecord,
    p.id AS p_id,
    group_concat(p.cloneId
        separator ',') AS clones,
    o.title
FROM
    `notes` AS o
        LEFT JOIN
    `pendingUpdates` AS p ON (o.id = p.originalId)
group by id;
```

this returns:

```
   +----+------------+-------------+------+--------+---------------------+
   | id | hasChanges | isNewRecord | p_id | clones | title               |
   +----+------------+-------------+------+--------+---------------------+
   |  1 | no         | no          | NULL |  NULL  | this is a test note |
   |  2 | no         | no          | NULL |  NULL  | note 2              |
   |  3 | yes        | no          |    1 |  4,5   | note 3              |
 ->|  4 | no         | no          | NULL |  NULL  | note 3              |
 ->|  5 | no         | no          | NULL |  NULL  | note 3              |
   |  6 | yes        | yes         |    3 |  6     | note 4              |
   +----+------------+-------------+------+--------+---------------------+
```

---

### Solution:

Here is the final solution I ended up using,  it is most similar to fthiella's.

Thanks again to all who helped out with this.

```
SELECT 
    m.id,
    if(m.max_pending IS NOT NULL, 'yes', 'no') hasChanges,
    if(m.id = pendingUpdates.cloneId, 'yes', 'no') isNew,
    m.clones,
    m.pendingIds,
    m.title
FROM (SELECT 
           Notes.id,
           MAX(pendingUpdates.id) max_pending,
          GROUP_CONCAT(pendingUpdates.id) pendingIds,
          GROUP_CONCAT(pendingUpdates.cloneId) clones,
          MAX(title) title
      FROM  Notes
      LEFT JOIN pendingUpdates ON Notes.id = pendingUpdates.originalId
      GROUP BY Notes.id
      ) m
          LEFT JOIN pendingUpdates ON m.max_pending = pendingUpdates.id
WHERE
    m.id NOT IN (SELECT 
                     cloneId
                 FROM pendingUpdates
                 WHERE cloneId NOT IN (SELECT 
                                          originalId
                                         FROM pendingUpdates)
                )
order by id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8566e/1/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your query this way (your original query makes use of some non-aggregated columns, and the value of those could be undetermined in some circumstances):

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  CASE WHEN m.max_pending IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END hasChanges,
  CASE WHEN m.id=pendingUpdates.cloneId
       THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END isNew,
  m.min_pending pid,
  m.clones,
  m.title
FROM (
  SELECT
    Notes.id,
    MAX(pendingUpdates.id) max_pending,
    MIN(pendingUpdates.id) min_pending,
    GROUP_CONCAT(pendingUpdates.cloneId) clones,
    MAX(title) title
  FROM
    Notes LEFT JOIN pendingUpdates
    ON Notes.id = pendingUpdates.originalId
  GROUP BY
    Notes.id) m LEFT JOIN pendingUpdates
  ON m.max_pending = pendingUpdates.id
WHERE
  m.id NOT IN (SELECT cloneId FROM pendingUpdates
               WHERE cloneId NOT IN (SELECT originalId FROM pendingUpdates))
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5496/1).

Answer (score 1):

you may look for this

```
   SELECT 
o.id,
if(o.id = p.originalId , 'yes', 'no') AS hasChanges,
if(p.cloneId = p.originalId,
    'yes',
    'no') AS isNewRecord,
p.id AS p_id,
group_concat(p.cloneId
    separator ',') AS clones,
o.title
FROM
`notes` AS o
    LEFT JOIN
`pendingUpdates` AS p ON (o.id = p.originalId)
where o.id in (select originalId from pendingUpdates)
or o.id in (select id from pendingUpdates)
group by id;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef98c/9)

Comment: This is nice, beat me to it but to be honest yours is cleaner than mine was

Comment: Well, thanks for your help, but that solution doesn't really work for all data.  It is working now because of a convenient overlap between user ids and row id's.  For example, if the users ids were 101,101,102 then this query doesn't work as expected.  Or if the row ids were 90-96...

Comment: you didnt say how you are choosing the o.id ??

Comment: o.id (==notes.id) is just an auto-increment INT column.  Likewise for the user column, there is a 'Users' table with a auto-increment INT 'id' column and this is where the 'user' data comes from.  It shouldn't matter to the query in either case.  In fact all the tables in this particular DB use auto-increment INT id's as their primary keys.